# WIll an Olympus TCON-17X teleconverter work on a Fujifilm X100 series camera?

Tags: olympus, teleconverter, fujifilm-x100

The X100 has a 49mm thread via a AR-X100 adapter. The Olympus TCON-17X has 55mm threads, so the connection should be no problem. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any known issues with using filter step-up rings?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22386/are-there-any-known-issues-with-using-filter-step-up-rings)

Answer (score 1):

**The only way to know what will happen is to try it.** As you state, "the connection should be no problem", just use a 49-55 step-up ring. However, the lens is 23mm, so the ring may be visible along the edges of the frame.

Step-up rings are fairly inexpensive, so if you already have the adapter and converter, you can go ahead and try it. Otherwise, consider you'll likely have a much better experience by using FujiFilm's native converters:

- Wide Conversion Lens WCL-X100 II - 0.8×, 23mm → 19 mm
- Tele Conversion Lens TCL-X100 II - 1.4×, 23mm → 33 mm